# Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key using WAMP

Tags: php, openssl, tcpdf, pkcs#7

I am trying to sign PDF using TCPDF, but I have got this error:

```
Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key in C:\wamp\www\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 7594.
```

My PHP version is 5.5.12 and TCPDF 6.2.11. Windows 7.

Other examples run well but this fails. I have tried:

```
'file://'.( dirname(FILE)).'./path/to/file' and again $certificate = 'file://'.realpath('../tcpdf.crt');
```

but does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think `file://` is not correct. You fetch die real path with `dirname(__FILE__)` that should be enough. So i prefer:

```
$certificate = __DIR__'/../tcpdf.crt';
```

`__DIR__` or `dirname(FILE)` is the path to the file you've in. To you can go back with `/../../` to your file depends on your folder location for your certificate files.

Answer (score 0):

You need the 'file://' prefix and the realpath to file:

```
//in your case
$certificate = 'file://'.realpath('../tcpdf.crt');
// OR for other cases
$certificate = 'file://'.realpath('/tcpdf.crt');
// OR
$certificate = 'file://'.realpath('C:/tcpdf.crt');
```